# nodejs dynamo parallel scan ( Segments )

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to run my scan queries in parallel and I'm somewhat succeeding. However the whole dividing the table into segments doesn't really offer true parallelism.

For instance if segment nr #3 has a match and if it exceeds 1MB it will still give me `LastEvaluatedKey` and I have to keep running the query in series. So when all the data is in one segment it's running the whole thing in series.

Am i missing something?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be…

…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
…Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem
…Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.